# In file included from dev c++

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently using dev++ for c++ programming, i just import a project in devc++ and gives error in including the header files, i try to gave the complete file path for the header files
. i have tried almost all the options available on stack over flow or rest of the sites please do help me..
[image]

Please clearly mention that how compiler will detect the include path or how this problem will be solved... thanks...

Comment: They are not using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you've tried everything on stackoverflow but in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257795/header-files-in-dev-c) answer Jose Luis Manrique suggest to put your #include after the `using namespace std` line. Have you tried this?

I don't use dev c++ myself but according to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/122488/) link, you can enter include paths in  tools->compiler options->Directories->C++ includes.

Comment: So you added the directory including `LexicalAnalysis.h` to the include path like I mentioned in the second paragraph?

Comment: If that fails, try adding `-Ipath\to\include\directory` to execute->parameters->parameters to pass to your program.